# The fundamental counting principle in reverse

Tags: combinatorics

> How many natural odd numbers are between $100$ and $999$ that have all different digits?

There are two conditions in this question: $(1)$the number must be odd and $(2)$must have all different digits. I thought that condition $1$ is more important. So, because tehere is five odd numbers, $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, the units position has $5$ choices. The tens position has $9$ choices, since it must be different from the units. The hundreds position has $7$ choices, because can't be $0$ and must be different from the previous positions.

One gets $7 \cdot 9 \cdot 5=315$. But using Excel I found that there are $320$ odd numbers with all different digits between $100$ and $999$. Where I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: You miscounted, because you didn't take into account when the tens digit is 0. In those cases, you have 8 choices for the first digit, not 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 5 ways to choose the last digit
- 8 ways to choose the hundreds digit (    not 0, not last digit chosen
  )
- 8 ways to choose tens digit ( not    either of previous digits )

$(5)(8)(8)=320$

Always select the restricted digits before the unrestricted ones. We are lucky the restrictions don't overlap, if they did we would need to break the problem into cases.